# Finding a minimum value for each group in a column _ Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have two columns Opp ID and Date, and I need to find for each Opp ID, which is the Minimum Date, so the result is new added column as Minimum Date [Here is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsNgF.jpg)

I am writing the formula as follow in Power Query:

#"Current step" = Table.AddColumn (#"Previous step", "Minimum Date",each Table.Group(#"Previous step","Opp Id",each List.Min(Table.Column(#"Previous Step","Date"))))
in
    #"Current step"

But I always get this error:

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Function to type List.
>
> Details:
>   Value=Function
>   Type=Type

Would anyone please help me to figure what's wrong there ?

Hang

Comment: Cross posted, which is generally not appreciated. I already provided an answer on TechNet: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9484372b-b667-4890-a5dd-52657aa574cd/finding-a-minimum-value-for-each-group-in-a-column?forum=powerquery

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"OppID"}, {{"All rows", each _, type table}, {"MinDate", each List.Min([Date]), type number}}),
    #"Expanded {0}" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All rows", {"Date"}, {"Date"})
in
    #"Expanded {0}"
```

Comment: Please explain your answer